# Solve primary key violation in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

While trying to insert some items into a table I get the following error:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Procedure dba_create_fake_orders, Line 95 [Batch Start Line 2]
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_OrderItem_1'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.OrderItem'. The duplicate key value is (10000, 100009).

Here's how my tables are set up and the following code is just a segment of the code used to insert those items to the table:

[Table Set UP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFYft.png)

```
INSERT INTO Orders(order_id, customer_id, sub_total, tax_total,
                   grand_total, date_created)
    SELECT 
        @order_id, @customer_id, 0, 0,
        0, @date_created

INSERT INTO OrderItem (order_id, quantity, game_id, price_id)
    SELECT
        @order_id, @quantity, game_id, price_id
    FROM
        GameVersion
    WHERE
        game_id = @game_id
```

`@order` and `@customer_id` are taken from a flat customer table and are chosen at random. The `OrderItem` table is empty always so I'm not sure why it's saying that there's a duplication error. The only tables that are populate is `Orders` and `GameVersion`.

`GameVersion` is populated way before and `Orders` is done just before `OrderItem`. I'm assuming the issue is that since I have to keys then it might be complaining since they might be the same number but I'm still not sure.

Comment: Run the SELECT query on its own. Look at the results. Does it have duplicates for the primary key?

Comment: What's the PK of OrderItem? it seems you set the order_id column as PK in OrderItem and that's wrong.

Comment: for OrderItem I have both game_id and game_id as primary keys. order_id is also the primary key for Orders

Comment: Did you check if you have duplicates in GameVersion table when you group by game_id?

Comment: So GameVersion doesn't have PK, I'm assuming that since game_id is a PK in OrderItem then that must be the reason that it complains

Comment: Run this query and tell me if you get any records: 
select count(asterisk sign), game_id from GameVersion GROUP BY game_id having count(asterisk sign)>1

Comment: I do get records in that query, for instance the first row says 1  5 100000

Comment: Then that's the issue, if you get more than one row it means you are not gonna insert unique values in the PK and the constraint is gonna error out.

Comment: so say that I remove game_id as PK in OrderItem, then I wouldn't have that issue ?

Comment: I'm not sure how that is causing the conflict?

Answer (score 0):

If the following query returns more than one row then it means your dataset has duplicate value in the column set you are using as PK in OrderItem.

```
select count(*), game_id from GameVersion GROUP BY game_id having count(*)>1
```